# There is a configuration for Disqus scripts?

Tags: html, disqus

I would like to be able to use Disqus script only as a input to comments.

For SEO I am getting the messages from Disqus API and loading together with my webpage. Now I would like to be able to set Disqus script in a way it displays only the area for new comments input.

Does anybody know if that is possible? Or where I can find a documentation with all parameters I can set to the script.

I already thought in hide that using CSS, but I would like to do it properly using the tool.

I appreciate any comment or idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think API Bindings can help you.
https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472115-libraries